# How to re-use a method from one component to the next

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that has grown rather large.  I decided to break it up into two components, but have found that the component I have split off needs to utilize a method from the original component.

What is the best way to consume a method from inside of an existing component?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time, one would have used `mixins` to achieve what you are looking to do. Since then, this article came out : https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html
They are still an option in my opinion but require discipline so that you don't overuse the concept.

Other options for you would be:

a) Bring the desired method up one level. By that I mean you could declare it in the container component and pass it along a `props` to the 2 childrens.

b) If the method is generic enough, declare it in an utility class that you would import in both components. (using `static` is an option as well)

c) any other innovative way ;) (just to say that these are not the only options)

Comment: Thank you!  creating a container component and then using function pointers FROM parent TO child did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Extend your base class with in a Split off version. If you use ES6 it would look something like this:

```
class Base extends React.Component {

    renderText () { return 'Hello'}

    render(){
        return <span>{this.renderText()}</span>
    }
}

class SplitOff extends Base {
    render() {
        return <span>{`${this.renderText()} World`}</span>
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1598/)